# Cuál es la diferencia entre un foreach con {} y otro foreach con endforeach?

Tags: php, foreach

A lo que me refiero es la diferencia entre este foreach con llaves y otro que termina con endforeach.

```
foreach($codigo as $key -> $val){
      //CODIGO
}
```

en cambio, con endforeach

```
   foreach ($codigo as $key -> $val) :
            //CODIGO
    endforeach;
```

¿O es exactamente lo mismo? solo es esa duda, gracias

Comment: Lo habitual es la primera sintaxis.., la segunda con el endforeach es una [sintaxis alternativa](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), ni mejor ni peor, solo alternativa

Comment: @masterguru convendría que lo escribas es una respuesta, indicando además que la forma correcta es `foreach($codigo as $key => $val){` no `foreach($codigo as $key -> $val){`, es decir, sustituir `->` por `=>`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Bien visto, ya he colocado la respuesta. Gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lo habitual es la primera sintaxis**, aunque tienes un error tipográfico en ella, tal como @A.Cedano ha detectado en los comentarios.
Donde pones esto:

```
foreach($codigo as $key -> $val){
```

debe ser así:

```
foreach($codigo as $key => $val){
```

es decir, utilizando el símbolo `=>`.

La segunda sintaxis, con el **`@endforeach`** es una sintaxis alternativa, **ni mejor ni peor**, solo alternativa, tal como se indica en su [documentación oficial del manual del PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).